# Visual Studio 2013: How to send app to second monitor upon finishing build?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

This question is solely about workflow in VS2013.  In VS2012, when I would build my app, VS would display the app on the second monitor attached to my system.  This was nice because I could see my IDE while I interacted with the app.  However, in VS2013, the app always just displays over the IDE, so I have "move it out of the way" just to get back to the code.  I would like VS2013 behavior to match that found in VS2012.  Is there a setting in the IDE that I can switch on to ensure the app displays on the second monitor?

I did find [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621794/debug-winrt-app-on-second-monitor-with-visual-studio-2012) on SO about this regarding VS2012, but the solution there does not work for Win8.1 using VS2013.  Is there an option for this?

Comment: It is possible to save the screen window position in for your application for the next run instance. I've done the this for debugging purposes to achieve what you are doing.  There are some examples out on the web

Comment: great, can you point me to some?  I didn't find any of those examples in all my googling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's not exactly the answer to your question - garaber has already addressed that - but also useful in this context is that you can move a window to a different display using the keyboard -

> windows-shift-left arrow

and

> windows-shift-right arrow

fast, easy way to move a window to an adjacent display (either to the right or the left)

EDIT:
should have noted that this is not confined to visual studio - this is a feature introduced with windows 7 and works with any window.

Comment: This seems closer to the solution I was looking for:  a non-programmatic one, and that focuses more on usability of the IDE.  Thanks!

Comment: i thought it wasn't exactly what you were seeking because the question was really stated as being about getting the window to start in the desired location, rather than moving it after it is open - nonetheless, this is something useful that any windows user should know to be able to move windows around easily and i'm glad it serves your purpose.

Comment: Thanks Dave! The essence of the question was:  `I would like VS2013 behavior to match that found in VS2012. Is there a setting in the IDE that I can switch on to ensure the app displays on the second monitor?`  It was more of a usability question, I thought.  I will try to be more explicit in future questions.

Comment: Now if we could just get visual studio to fire the Onload event or resize event when that key combo is triggered, that would be just Fab!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of good links that will show you how to do what you're wanting:

- [Save and restore form position and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92540/save-and-restore-form-position-and-size)
- [Restoring window size and position with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937298/restoring-window-size-position-with-multiple-monitors)

Comment: With these examples I would wrap them around conditional compiles for debugging

Comment: thank you for providing those, but I should have mentioned I'm working with HTML5 / CSS / WinJS to code, so I don't think I can implement this code around compiler directives.

Comment: So you app is running in a browser? Please be more precise do we can help.

Comment: It's a Windows Store App coded in javascript and makes use of the WinJS library.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your principal screen, and it works :

> In, Screen Resolution : set your second screen as a principal screen.